# keep-alive TTL in Go Transport never closes connections

Tags: go, tcp, httpserver, keep-alive, aws-alb

I have an application hosted on AWS which is running on Production creates an http server as mentioned in the below sample code. There is default timeout of 180 seconds in the go library. So, ideally connections not used should be closed after 180 seconds.

```
myMux := http.NewServeMux()
myMux.Handle("/SOME_PATH", appHandler{myHandler})
err = http.ListenAndServe(viper.GetString("handler.port"), myMux)
```

The problem is when traffic increases on the application, number of connections increases. But when traffic comes down number of connections remains same.

I am using `go version go1.10 linux/amd64` and this application is behind Amazon ALB.

**Edited question:**

As you can see the rate at which connections are decreasing is very slow when application is behind ALB. So, what could be the problem
[image]

Comment: Behind an ALB they may not be in an idle keep-alive state for 180s, they may be active for e.g. health checks. Try running it with a load generator pointed directly at the service without a load balancer and see what it does.

Comment: I tried without ALB connections get closed after `time_wait` state, where as with ALB it is not exhibiting the same behaviour

Comment: That sounds right, for the reason stated in my original comment. Nothing is wrong, it's just how load balancers work.

Comment: @Adrian But there should be only few connetions which are there for heath checks  not like in thousands of connetions, right? As I have mentioned in the graph connections are taking too long to come to normal

Comment: Not just for health checks, for actual traffic. The load balancer will maintain keep-alive connections to the backing server in order to route traffic, and the number of connections it holds open will be based on volume.

Comment: @Adrian Actually I removed the instances from load balancer to check whether connections are coming down or not. But still all the connections are in keep-alive state and after 180secs they again go to keep-alive state.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your server you should add timeouts appropriate for your application, for example

```
srv := &http.Server{
    ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
    IdleTimeout:  180 * time.Second,
    Handler:      myMux,
}
```

With this the idle connections should get turned off. If it's an upstream load balancer sending health checks on that many connections the solution would be different.